# JavaScript - Set function to return all items based on 1 or 2 selected tags (NO jQUERY)

Tags: javascript

I have some JavaScrip that is meant to check if there are any media tags selected or industry tags selected--this is so the portfolio items can be sorted and displayed accordingly in the browser.

What I have almost works 100%, but I can't figure out how to make it so that if only a media tag is selected or if only an industry tag is selected, the portfolio items should still be sorted accordingly. Currently, you have to select a media tag AND an industry tag, but I'd like users to be able to search using just a media tag OR just an industry tag.

Here is what I want to accomplish: If only a media tag is selected, then get all portfolio pieces that are associated with that media tag. If only an industry tag is selected, get all portfolio items that are associated with that industry tag. If a media tag AND industry tag are selected at the same time, get all portfolio items that are associated with BOTH.

Vanilla JS isn't my strong point so forgive me if this is a dumb question, but this has had me stumped for hours now.

No jQuery answers, please, as this whole page's functionality is built using JavaScript.

Here is the function:

```
var update = function () {
    closeDrawer();
    // update ui to reflect tag changes
    // get our list of items to display

    var itemsToDisplay = [];
    var currentMediaTag = controlsContainer.querySelector('.media.selected');
    var currentIndustryTag = controlsContainer.querySelector('.industry.selected');

    if (currentMediaTag != "" && currentMediaTag != null) {
        selectedMediaFilter = currentMediaTag.innerHTML;
    }

    if (currentIndustryTag != "" && currentIndustryTag != null) {
        selectedIndustryFilter = currentIndustryTag.innerHTML;
    }

    if (selectedMediaFilter == "" && selectedIndustryFilter == "") {
        itemsToDisplay = portfolioItems.filter(function (item) {
            return item.preferred;
        });

    } else {
        itemsToDisplay = portfolioItems.filter(function (item) {
            var mediaTags = item.media_tags,
                industryTags = item.industry_tags;

            if(industryTags.indexOf(selectedIndustryFilter) < 0){
                return false;
            }
            else if(mediaTags.indexOf(selectedMediaFilter) < 0){
                return false;
            }

            else{
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    renderItems(itemsToDisplay);
}
```

Not entirely sure it's necessary but just in case, here is the complete JS file that handles the portfolio page:

```
(function ($) {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
        // for portfolio interaction
        var portfolioGrid = (function () {
            var gridSize = undefined,
                parentContainer = document.querySelector('.portfolio-item-container');
            containers = parentContainer.querySelectorAll('.view'),
                drawer = parentContainer.querySelector('.drawer'),
                bannerContainer = drawer.querySelector('.banner-container'),
                thumbsContainer = drawer.querySelector('.thumbs-container'),
                descriptionContainer = drawer.querySelector('.client-description'),
                clientNameContainer = drawer.querySelector('.client-name'),
                controlsContainer = document.querySelector('.portfolio-controls-container'),
                selectedMediaFilter = "", selectedIndustryFilter = "";

            var setGridSize = function () {
                var windowSize = window.innerWidth,
                    previousGridSize = gridSize;

                if (windowSize > 1800) {
                    gridSize = 5;
                } else if (windowSize > 900) {
                    gridSize = 4;
                } else if (windowSize > 600 && windowSize <= 900) {
                    gridSize = 3;
                } else {
                    gridSize = 2;
                }

                if (previousGridSize != gridSize) {
                    closeDrawer();
                }
            };

            var attachResize = function () {
                window.onresize = function () {
                    setGridSize();
                };
            };

            var getRowClicked = function (boxNumber) {
                return Math.ceil(boxNumber / gridSize);
            };

            var getLeftSibling = function (row) {
                var cI = row * gridSize;
                return containers[cI >= containers.length ? containers.length - 1 : cI];
            };

            var openDrawer = function () {
                drawer.className = 'drawer';
                scrollToBanner();
            };

            var scrollToBanner = function () {
                var mainContainer = document.querySelector('#main-container'),
                    mainBounding = mainContainer.getBoundingClientRect(),
                    scrollY = (drawer.offsetTop - mainBounding.bottom) - 10,
                    currentTop = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top;

                animate(document.body, "scrollTop", "", document.body.scrollTop, scrollY, 200, true);
            };

            var animate = function (elem, style, unit, from, to, time, prop) {
                if (!elem) return;
                var start = new Date().getTime(),
                    timer = setInterval(function () {
                        var step = Math.min(1, (new Date().getTime() - start) / time);
                        if (prop) {
                            elem[style] = (from + step * (to - from)) + unit;
                        } else {
                            elem.style[style] = (from + step * (to - from)) + unit;
                        }
                        if (step == 1) clearInterval(timer);
                    }, 25);
                elem.style[style] = from + unit;
            }

            var closeDrawer = function () {
                drawer.className = 'drawer hidden';
            };

            var cleanDrawer = function () {
                bannerContainer.innerHTML = "";
                clientNameContainer.innerHTML = "";
                descriptionContainer.innerHTML = "";
                thumbsContainer.innerHTML = "";
            };

            var resetThumbs = function () {
                Array.prototype.forEach.call(thumbsContainer.querySelectorAll('.thumb'), function (t) {
                    t.className = "thumb";
                });
            };

            var handleBannerItem = function (item) {
                bannerContainer.innerHTML = "";
                if (item.youtube) {
                    var videoContainer = document.createElement('div'),
                        iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

                    videoContainer.className = "videowrapper";
                    iframe.className = "youtube-video";
                    iframe.src = "https://youtube.com/embed/" + item.youtube;
                    videoContainer.appendChild(iframe);
                    bannerContainer.appendChild(videoContainer);
                } else if (item.soundcloud) {
                    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                    iframe.src = item.soundcloud;
                    iframe.className = "soundcloud-embed";
                    bannerContainer.appendChild(iframe);
                } else if (item.banner) {
                    var bannerImage = document.createElement('img');
                    bannerImage.src = item.banner;
                    bannerContainer.appendChild(bannerImage);
                }
            };

            var attachClick = function () {
                Array.prototype.forEach.call(containers, function (n, i) {
                    n.querySelector('a.info').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });

                    n.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                        var boxNumber = i + 1,
                            row = getRowClicked(boxNumber);
                        var containerIndex = row * gridSize;
                        if (containerIndex >= containers.length) {
                            // we're inserting drawer at the end
                            parentContainer.appendChild(drawer);
                        } else {
                            // we're inserting drawer in the middle somewhere
                            var leftSiblingNode = getLeftSibling(row);
                            leftSiblingNode.parentNode.insertBefore(drawer, leftSiblingNode);
                        }
                        // populate
                        cleanDrawer();
                        var mediaFilterSelected = document.querySelector('.media-tags .tag-container .selected');
                        var selectedFilters = "";
                        if (mediaFilterSelected != "" && mediaFilterSelected != null) {
                            selectedFilters = mediaFilterSelected.innerHTML;
                        }
                        var portfolioItemName = '';
                        var selectedID = this.getAttribute('data-portfolio-item-id');
                        var data = portfolioItems.filter(function (item) {
                            portfolioItemName = item.name;
                            return item.id === selectedID;
                        })[0];

                        clientNameContainer.innerHTML = data.name;
                        descriptionContainer.innerHTML = data.description;
                        var childItems = data.child_items;

                        //We will group the child items by media tag and target the unique instance from each group to get the right main banner
                        Array.prototype.groupBy = function (prop) {
                            return this.reduce(function (groups, item) {
                                var val = item[prop];
                                groups[val] = groups[val] || [];
                                groups[val].push(item);
                                return groups;
                            }, {});
                        }
                        var byTag = childItems.groupBy('media_tags');
                        if (childItems.length > 0) {
                            handleBannerItem(childItems[0]);
                            var byTagValues = Object.values(byTag);
                            byTagValues.forEach(function (tagValue) {
                                for (var t = 0; t < tagValue.length; t++) {
                                    if (tagValue[t].media_tags == selectedFilters) {
                                        handleBannerItem(tagValue[0]);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            childItems.forEach(function (item, i) {
                                var img = document.createElement('img'),
                                    container = document.createElement('div'),
                                    label = document.createElement('p');
                                container.appendChild(img);
                                var mediaTags = item.media_tags;

                                container.className = "thumb";
                                label.className = "childLabelInactive thumbLbl";
                                thumbsContainer.appendChild(container);
                                if (selectedFilters.length > 0 && mediaTags.length > 0) {
                                    for (var x = 0; x < mediaTags.length; x++) {
                                        if (mediaTags[x] == selectedFilters) {
                                            container.className = "thumb active";
                                            label.className = "childLabel thumbLbl";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    container.className = i == 0 ? "thumb active" : "thumb";
                                }

                                img.src = item.thumb;
                                if (item.media_tags != 0 && item.media_tags != null) {
                                    childMediaTags = item.media_tags;
                                    childMediaTags.forEach(function (cMTag) {
                                        varLabelTxt = document.createTextNode(cMTag);
                                        container.appendChild(label);
                                        label.appendChild(varLabelTxt);
                                    });
                                }
                                img.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                                    scrollToBanner();
                                    resetThumbs();
                                    handleBannerItem(item);
                                    container.className = "thumb active";
                                });
                            });
                        }
                        openDrawer();
                    });
                });
            };

            var preloadImages = function () {
                portfolioItems.forEach(function (item) {
                    var childItems = item.child_items;
                    childItems.forEach(function (child) {
                        (new Image()).src = child.banner;
                        (new Image()).src = child.thumb;
                    });
                });
            };

//////////////////////////////////// UPDATE FUNCTION /////////////////////////////////////
            var update = function () {
                closeDrawer();
                // update ui to reflect tag changes
                // get our list of items to display

                var itemsToDisplay = [];
                var currentMediaTag = controlsContainer.querySelector('.media.selected');
                var currentIndustryTag = controlsContainer.querySelector('.industry.selected');

                if (currentMediaTag != "" && currentMediaTag != null) {
                    selectedMediaFilter = currentMediaTag.innerHTML;
                }

                if (currentIndustryTag != "" && currentIndustryTag != null) {
                    selectedIndustryFilter = currentIndustryTag.innerHTML;
                }

                if (selectedMediaFilter == "" && selectedIndustryFilter == "") {
                    itemsToDisplay = portfolioItems.filter(function (item) {
                        return item.preferred;
                    });

                } else {
                    itemsToDisplay = portfolioItems.filter(function (item) {
                        var mediaTags = item.media_tags,
                            industryTags = item.industry_tags;

                        if (industryTags.indexOf(selectedIndustryFilter) < 0) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        else if (mediaTags.indexOf(selectedMediaFilter) < 0) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        else {
                            return true;
                        }

                    });
                }

                renderItems(itemsToDisplay);
            }

//////////////////////////////////// RENDERITEMS FUNCTION /////////////////////////////////////

            var renderItems = function (items) {
                var children = parentContainer.querySelectorAll('.view');
                Array.prototype.forEach.call(children, function (child) {
                    // remove all event listeners then remove child
                    parentContainer.removeChild(child);
                });

                items.forEach(function (item) {

                    var container = document.createElement('div'),
                        thumb = document.createElement('img'),
                        mask = document.createElement('div'),
                        title = document.createElement('h6'),
                        excerpt = document.createElement('p'),
                        link = document.createElement('a');

                    container.className = "view view-tenth";
                    container.setAttribute('data-portfolio-item-id', item.id);

                    thumb.src = item.thumb;

                    mask.className = "mask";

                    title.innerHTML = item.name;
                    excerpt.innerHTML = item.excerpt;

                    link.href = "#";
                    link.className = "info";
                    link.innerHTML = "View Work";

                    container.appendChild(thumb);
                    container.appendChild(mask);

                    mask.appendChild(title);
                    mask.appendChild(excerpt);
                    mask.appendChild(link);
                    parentContainer.insertBefore(container, drawer);
                });

                containers = parentContainer.querySelectorAll('.view');
                attachClick();
            };

            var filterHandler = function (linkNode, tagType) {

                var prevSelection = document.querySelector("." + tagType + '.selected');
                if (prevSelection != "" && prevSelection != null) {
                    prevSelection.className = tagType + ' tag';
                }

                linkNode.className = tagType + ' tag selected';
                update();
            };

            var clearFilters = function (nodeList, filterType) {
                Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodeList, function (node) {
                    node.className = filterType + " tag";
                    console.log("Clear filters function called");
                });
            }

            var attachFilters = function () {
                var mediaFilters = controlsContainer.querySelectorAll('.tag.media'),
                    industryFilters = controlsContainer.querySelectorAll('.tag.industry'),
                    filterToggle = controlsContainer.querySelectorAll('.filter-toggle');

                // resets
                controlsContainer.querySelector('.media-tags .reset')
                    .addEventListener('click',
                    function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        selectedMediaFilter = "";
                        clearFilters(controlsContainer.querySelectorAll('.media-tags a.tag'), "media");
                        update();
                    }
                );

                controlsContainer.querySelector('.industry-tags .reset')
                    .addEventListener('click',
                    function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        selectedIndustryFilter = "";
                        clearFilters(controlsContainer.querySelectorAll('.industry-tags a.tag'), "industry");

                        update();
                    }
                );

                Array.prototype.forEach.call(filterToggle, function (toggle) {
                    toggle.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                        if (controlsContainer.className.indexOf('open') < 0) {
                            controlsContainer.className += ' open';
                        } else {
                            controlsContainer.className = controlsContainer.className.replace('open', '');
                        }
                    });
                });

                //Attaches a click event to each media tag "button"
                Array.prototype.forEach.call(mediaFilters, function (filter) {
                    filter.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        // var selectedMediaFilter = controlsContainer.querySelector('.media.selected');
                        //console.log("Media tag: " +this.innerHTML); *THIS WORKS*
                        filterHandler(this, "media");
                    });
                });

                Array.prototype.forEach.call(industryFilters, function (filter) {
                    filter.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        //  var selectedIndustryFilter = this.querySelector('.industry.selected');
                        //  console.log("Industry tag: " +this.innerHTML); *THIS WORKS*

                        filterHandler(this, "industry");
                    });
                });
            };

            return {
                init: function () {
                    setGridSize();
                    attachResize();
                    attachClick();
                    preloadImages();

                    // portfolio page
                    if (controlsContainer) {
                        attachFilters();
                    }
                }
            };
        })();

        portfolioGrid.init();
    });
}());

$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the portfolio items should still be sorted accordingly. "? As it looks to me, the function should just work fine if only one of the two tags is selected? The only problem I can see, is that you don't reset a filter to an empty string if one of your selectors (f.e. `.querySelector('.media.selected')`) doesn't find anything.

Comment: element.querySelector will return the first matching item found.  I suspect you want element.querySelectorAll, which returns all matching items.

Answer (score 1):

```
        if(industryTags.indexOf(selectedIndustryFilter) < 0){
            return false;
        }
        else if(mediaTags.indexOf(selectedMediaFilter) < 0){
            return false;
        }
```

That part is giving you headaches. Whenever no industry tag or media tag is selected this will exit the function.

Change to:

```
        if(industryTags.indexOf(selectedIndustryFilter) < 0 && mediaTags.indexOf(selectedMediaFilter) < 0){
            return false;
        }
```

Now it will test if at least one tag is selected. If so then render items.

Comment: I gave that a try but the results are still the same: In order to filter the portfolio items, I need to select a media tag and industry tag. But I want to be able to sort the portfolio items by just a media tag or by just an industry tag as well.

Comment: sounds like a UI issue, can you highlight the part of your code that checks if the user has selected both?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Both of your posts actually helped me find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I made a change just to experiment with an idea, and this setup works:

```
  if((selectedIndustryFilter !="" && industryTags.indexOf(selectedIndustryFilter) < 0) || (selectedMediaFilter !="" && mediaTags.indexOf(selectedMediaFilter) < 0)){
        return false;
  }
  return true;
```

Not sure if it's the best solution ever but it seems to work and I'm not going to complain.